# Problem with creating new AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am having a problem with creating a application using Angular JS.
I have tried it all ways as per my knowledge. I reinstalled nodejs and angularjs again and again but when I move forward to create a new application (ng new my-app), it gives me schematic workflow failed error.
i went to the site they provided me to check the issue. but i won't understand how to fix it.

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGHoI.png)

Comment: i tried installing the packages one by one but @angular-devkit/build-angular and types/node give me npm err!

Comment: Solved !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: installing all the dependencies by yourself helped.

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular firslt i used npm cache clean --force

Comment: then npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular and it worked